# Read Twilio sms as REST from pre-bought phone number

Tags: c#, rest, twilio

I'm trying to figure out twilio. I need to use a predefined phone number, so I bought one. But I do not see any way of actually getting sms's from it as REST. It seems like twilio follows more complicated schemas when getting texts from phone numbers. Like there is an option for WebHook, TwiML Bin, etc. Is there just a REST url I can access to get all the sms's from this number?

I was able to do this:

```
        var messages = MessageResource.Read(limit: 20);
```

But this seems to allow me to read messages from all my sms's, even those that are not coming from a fixed phone number.

Background: my app will be a windows app, so I need a simplest way to read sms's possible. No web hooks and I do not need to send sms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured this out. It was very easy:

```
        var messages = MessageResource.Read(limit: 20, to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+12345678901"));
```

Where `+12345678901` is your registered phone number in Twilio system in + format.